# Как сделать нестандартную раскладку без доп оберток?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать нестандартную раскладку без доп оберток?[image: Как сделать нестандартную раскладку без доп оберток?]

Comment: Уточните, что вы подразумеваете под *нестандартной раскладкой* и *доп обёртками*

Comment: @T0xee.n17, то что на скрине. Имею ввиду, чтобы был враппер. В нем итемы. Всё

Comment: `position: absolute` 

Comment: @AlexeyTen 

Answer (score 2):

> Как сделать нестандартную раскладку без доп оберток?

Есть вариант вывода в несколько колонок. В примере их две.

```css
ul {
    column-count: 2;
}
ul > li:first-child {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Никто не знает как это правильно сделать, но вот ещё вариант))

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}
li {
  
}
.devider {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="devider"></li>
  <li class="devider"></li>
  <li class="devider"></li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```